# Div not showing up in responsive layout

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a responsive wordpress website which shows nicely on desktops. But somehow the whole layout is broken on smaller screens and the products `div` on homepage doesn't even display up there. `.featured_products` is the `ul` which you see on home page but it disappears as soon you resize your browser to smaller mobile size.

Here is my [website](http://daccordinc.com/daccor/).

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of a media queries in your stylesheet which starts at line `5811` in `style.css`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px)
```

And then this part in the media query which starts at line `6149` in `style.css`

```
#subcontent2 {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please change the code

```
#subcontent2{
display:none;
}
```

and also check this jsfiidle for your solution

http://jsfiddle.net/wpEwZ/